# telegram-bot - ошибка unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Когда я отправляю документ с помощью функции `send_doc` в боте `telegram`, я получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> TypeError: send_document() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document'

Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

```
import telebot
import json
# import schedule
import os 

bot = telebot.TeleBot("1069003778:AAGQWy0_afe2JX4qv1rDHvoFIyhNBiYhlag")

@bot.message_handler(commands = ["start"])
def start_message(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ваше имя!")
  if message.text:
      print("Hello")
      bot.send_document(chat_id=message.chat.id, document=open('/home/ceasar/Desktop/python 2019/telebot/indexx.txt', 'rb'))
  else:
      pass

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])  
def send_message(message):

  global name
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что вы сделали?")
  name = message.text
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, send_text2)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_text2(message):

  global answer1
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Что вы будете делать?")
  answer1 = message.text
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, send_text3)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_text3(message):

  global answer2
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Какие сложности?")
  answer2 = message.text
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, send_stiker)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_stiker(message):

    global answer3
    answer3 = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Спасибо за ответы! Хорошего дня!")
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id,"CAADAQAD7QUAAsvEUgn-hpga09m6UhYE")


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Очень просто исправить: не передавать несуществующий аргумент по имени document.

Comment: @Эникейщик То есть просто не писать "document ="? А просто записать туда ссылку? Если так, то там выводит другую ошибку. "positional argument follows keyword argument"

Comment: Конечно же нет. Надо открыть документацию и посмотреть, как нужно делать.

Comment: vse perechital, nichego ne rabotaet

Answer (score 1):

Вместо несуществующего аргумента вставить существующий `data`.

```
bot.send_document(chat_id=message.chat.id, data=open('/home/ceasar/Desktop/python 2019/telebot/indexx.txt', 'rb'))
```

В [официальной документации](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py) всё описано.